# Connecting both brushed DC motor and brushless DC motor to a battery

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, lithium-polymer

Warning: I am robotics beginner!!!

Hi,

I am working on a robot car in which four tyres are connected to brushed DC motor controlled using Arduino and Arduino motor shield. Also it has one brushless motor for another part. Brushless motor is NOT controlled through Arduino motor shield.

I am using 8000 mAh, 11.1 V LIPO battery. I am planning to connect Arduino motor shield and brushless motor in parallel to battery.

I have following doubts in case I make above mentioned connections.

If brushless motor draws more current will Arduino motor shield also get more current? I am worried because Arduino motor shield has max current limit way less than brushless motor can need. So can such
connections burn my Arduino board and motor shield?

Comment: You cannot connect a brushless motor directly to a power supply. You must have a special brushless driver. Do you have a brushless driver? You never mentioned one. Your concerns about parallel are unwarranted because they connected are in parallel. If you have two water pipes coming from the same place but running to different places, does an increase of water flow in one increase the water flow in the other?

Comment: Your various components should not draw power through each other, but individually from the supply through a common fuse.  High current draw from one load can and *will* typically cause the battery voltage to drop, which can indeed be a problem for the operation of other loads.  At an extreme it will probably cause your on-board computer to crash and restart, though proper design will usually mean a 3-cell pack doesn't droop *that* far (a single cell one would however!).

Comment: @DKNguyen I have connected brush less motor to esc and esc to battery. Thanks. I got your point.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks a lot for answer and mentioning some possibilities. It helped. I am using 3 cell pack.